# Alternative to possessive quantifier in python

Tags: python, regex, quantifiers

I am trying to match all occurences of the String `Article` followed by a number (single or more digits) which are *not* followed by an opening parentheses. In Sublime Text, I am using the following regex:

```
Article\s[0-9]++(?!\()
```

to search the following String:

```
Article 29
Article 30(1)
```

which does not match `Article 30(1)` (as I expect it to) but `Article 29` and `Article 1`.

When attempting to do the same in Python (3) using

```
import re
article_list = re.findall(r'Article\s[0-9]++(?!\()', "Article 30(1)")
```

I get an the following Error as I am using a (nested) possessive quantifier which is not supported by Python regex. Is there any way to  match what I want it (not) to match in Python?

Comment: Python has support for possessive quantifiers as of 3.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Python 3.11 Update**

Possessive quantifiers and atomic groups are now supported. See [What’s New In Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#re):

> Atomic grouping (`(?>...)`) and possessive quantifiers (`*+`, `++`, `?+`, `{m,n}+`) are now supported in regular expressions. (Contributed by Jeffrey C. Jacobs and Serhiy Storchaka in [bpo-433030](https://bugs.python.org/issue?@action=redirect&bpo=433030).)

That  means,  `re.findall(r'Article\s[0-9]++(?!\()', "Article 30(1)")` should now work as expected.

**Additional reference**:

- [Atomic Grouping](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)
- [Possessive Quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

**In short**: these constructs disallow backtracking into the quantified pattern.

Here, in `[0-9]++(?!\()`, the digits will be matched and consumed, and the negative lookahead will be checked *only once*, right after the last digit consumed with `[0-9]++`, and if there is no `(` after that digit, the regex match will fail, and no match will be returned. If you use `[0-9]+(?!\()`, the regex engine would backtrack upon matching the last digit and finding out that there is no `(` after it, it would re-position its search index right before the last digit matched with `[0-9]+` and - righteously confirming the last digit is not a  `(` char - will return a match with the last digit in that number truncated.

**Legacy answer**

Python `re` does not support possessive quantifiers. You may consider using [Python PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) instead, that supports this type of quantifiers. Or use the following work-arounds.

You need to either add a digit to the lookahead:

```
Article\s[0-9]+(?![(0-9])
                    ^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGRRUt/1).

Alternatively, use a word boundary:

```
Article\s[0-9]+\b(?!\()
                ^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/02byCw/1).

Answer (score 9):

You can also emulate an atomic group `(?>...)` around what you want to match, using the `(?=(...))\1` workaround:

```
(?=(Article\s[0-9]+))\1(?!\()
```

*(a lookahead behaves naturally like an a atomic group, all you need is a capture and a backreference)*

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional information to the work-arounds:

From Python 3.11 on, the `re` module supports atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers, see https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#re and https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/34627.