# Regex/Python: Substitution in Python when the Regex already do the substitution

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove duplicate lines with this regex that works great:

```
(.*+)\n*(\1\n+)*
```

But when I try to use it in Python it doesn't work:

```
response1 = re.sub(r'(.*+)\n*', r'(\1\n+)*', response1)
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: re.error
multiple repeat at position 3
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to possessive quantifier in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458122/alternative-to-possessive-quantifier-in-python)

Comment: You could also use `[^\n]` instead of `.` to achieve the same effect

Comment: I don't have a problem with quantifiers nor the Regex itself, I'm trying to make it work in Python

Comment: The possessive quantifier *is* the problem - native Python doesn't support them.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the post you've sent, but I've no idea what it's talking about. I'm new to Python and Rege unfortunately.

Comment: Remove the possessive quantifier and use `[^\n]` instead of `.`. Also, the replacement string should just be the replacement string (possibly with ``\`` groups), not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "multiple repeat at position 3" problem is with the regex:

```
.*+
```

You can use either ".*" or ".+". Something like the following should remove consecutive duplicated lines:

```
response = """A
A    
A
B
B
A
A
"""
print(re.sub(r'(.*\n)(\1)+', r'\2', response))
```

Output

```
A
B
A
```

Comment: I used your code and got this error: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Likely 'response' is not a string. What is 'response'